# Edit package.json from command line

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I'm trying to add or edit a variable in my package.json from a shell script. So if i have a package.json like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "description": "Project by @DerZyklop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  ...
```

I want a command like

```
npm config set foo bar
```

that adds a new field like

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "description": "Project by @DerZyklop",
  "foo": "bar",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  ...
```

...but unfortunately `npm config set` just edits the `~/.npmrc` and not my package.json.

Comment: you can just open it with nano and edit it manually...

Comment: @MightyPork sorry if i haven'd expressed myself well enaugh. in the end i want to have a shell script that (among other tasks) edits one of the values inside package.json.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The `package.json` is just a `json` file, so you could use the tool [`json`](http://trentm.com/json). To install it use:

```
npm install -g json
```

Then you can edit a file in-place. More information [here](http://trentm.com/json/#FEATURE-In-place-editing).

### Example

```
$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "description": "Project by @DerZyklop",
  "version": "0.0.0"
}

$ json -I -f package.json -e "this.foo=\"bar\""
json: updated "package.json" in-place

$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "description": "Project by @DerZyklop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. although i already wrote my script in node [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685998/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-json-file-and-save-it-through-node-js). But i also testet your proposal and it works as well.

Comment: How can "bar" be a variable instead of a concrete value? Tried using an environmental variable but didn't replace it

Comment: @masimakopoulos: assuming that you are talking about bash, string interpolation is only available for double-quoted strings. So you need to swap single-quotes and double-quotes like this: `"this.foo='$A'"`. (This is normal bash behavior, so you can test it with `echo "this.foo='$A'"`)

Comment: Thanks. I used your approach to add the default "start" key pointing to a index.js script in my package.json (which was not a default included by Yarn but was called when running my Docker image) `npm install -g json; json --in-place -f package.json -e 'this.scripts={"start": "node index.js"}'`

Comment: Example didn't work for me (something must have changed) due to quoting issue described here: https://github.com/trentm/json/issues/117#issuecomment-322848900 - the command that works for me is using double quotes like this: json -I -f package.json -e "this.foo=\"bar\""

Comment: If you only have the `json` package installed as a project dependency, use `npx json` when running the command.

Comment: if has special char, use this way.   json -I -f application/package.json -e 'this.devDependencies["@package/xml-loader"]="2.2.21-canary"'

Answer (score 53):

You do have a **native NPM command:**

```
npm pkg set 'scripts.test'='jest'
```

Which is really helpful when you want to share a command. Instead of asking someone to install some cli tool, you can simply share this.

BTW, it's even more helpful when you use **NPM workspaces**, in which case you can change all the packages together:

```
npm pkg set 'scripts.test'='jest' -ws
```

Comment: It's 2022 and this should be the accepted answer. It's simplest, does exactly what the question asks for and doesn't use any extra tools.

Comment: Is there equivalent command for this in yarn?

Comment: Yes. Also available in yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/config/set (`yarn config set 'scripts.test' 'jest'`)

Comment: What about for any JSON file?

Answer (score 19):

If you don't want to install anything, you can also use a one-line script to modify the `package.json`:

```
node -e "let pkg=require('./package.json'); pkg.homepage='${CI_PAGES_URL}'; require('fs').writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2));"
```

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to install [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) or [json](http://trentm.com/json), you can also do

```
echo "`jq '.foo="bar"' package.json`" > package.json
```

Comment: I love this one ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) and [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) (moreutils package) like this :

```
jq '.foo="bar"' package.json | sponge package.json
```

With an environment variable :

```
jq --arg h "$HOMEPAGE" '.homepage=$h' package.json | sponge package.json
```

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to update only the `version` property in `package.json` and this is what worked for me:

```bash
# this sets the version 
# in package.json to 1.0.2
npm version 1.0.2 # creates a git-tag too
npm version 1.0.2 --no-git-tag-version # only changes the version without creating a git-tag
```

Comment: Keep in mind it [also creates tags for that version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-version#description). If they're not desired, use `--no-git-tag-version`.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a npm package for doing this called `npe`: https://github.com/zeke/npe

```
cd some/node/project

# Get stuff from package.json
npe name
npe scripts
npe scripts.test
npe repository.url
open $(npe repository.url)

# Set stuff in package.json
npe name foo
npe scripts.start "node index.js"

# Keywords string will be turned into an array
# If commas are present, they'll be the delimiter. Otherwise spaces.
npe keywords "foo, bar, cheese whiz"
npe keywords "foo bar baz"

# The current working directory's package.json is used by default,
# but you can point to another package file with a flag:
npe name --package=some/other/package.json
npe name other --package=some/other/package.json
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete a key?