# Adding npm package.json scripts per console command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

If you use `npm install <module> --save` it writes this module into the `package.json`, which is very useful.

The `package.json` has an area for scripts. I want to add some scripts here automatically, so what would be useful would be a command to use add scripts here instead of opening the files yourself.

Something like `npm add-script <name> <command>`

Is there really nothing like this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329241/edit-package-json-from-commandline

Comment: Also look at [npm-add-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-add-script).

Answer (score 4):

Yo can use [npm add script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-add-script) library.

- Install the library in your project:

  ```
  npm install -g npm-add-script
  ```
- Use it, like this `npmAddScript -k <name> -v <command>`, for example:

  ```
  npmAddScript -k test -v "node test.js"
  ```

More info in the official page of [npm add script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-add-script).

Comment: This is actually pretty helpful. Didn't expect it to be, but it is.