# How to edit a .js file with nodes

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to simply open up a JSON data script with nodejs and edit it... *as javascript* ...

```
// my json data
{
    people : [{
        name : 'Joe',
        hobby : 'hunting',
        job : 'accountant'
    },{
        name : 'William',
        hobby : 'chess',
        job : 'manager'
    }]
}
```

i just want to do something like e.g.

```
people[0].name = 'Joseph'
```

so i'm trying

```
fs.open('/path/to/file', 'r+', function(err, fd){
    // not really sure what to do from here...
})
```

there are plenty of answers about how to read/write text files... i just thought there might be an easier way for the case of a file in JSON

Whoops this is a repeat question - please see an earlier response here

[How to update a value in a json file and save it through node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10685998/1094784)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update a value in a json file and save it through node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685998/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-json-file-and-save-it-through-node-js)

Answer (score 3):

Parse the JSON using `JSON.parse()`, modify the parsed object, turn it back into a new string using `JSON.stringify()`, then save the string to the file.