# How to read/write to a JSON file in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, read-write

I am fairly new to node.js and i am wondering how to (or even if) i can read and write to a JSON file. I am trying to create an accessible punishment history.
Ideally i would want to be able to create something along the lines of this:

```
{
"punishments": {
    "users": {
      "<example user who has a punishment history>": {
        "punishment-1567346": {
          "punishment-id": "1567346",
          "punishment-type": "mute",
          "punishment-reason": "<reason>"
        },
        "punishment-1567347": {
          "punishment-id": "1567347",
          "punishment-type": "ban",
          "punishment-reason": "<reason>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then i would have a way to access the formatted punishment history. I genuinely have no clue where to start.

Comment: Very thorough article on this here: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/

Comment: @thanhdx - wrong context - not from the browser, from NodeJS

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yeah, I've just restract the flag. Sorry.

Comment: Here's a better one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671321/how-to-write-update-new-json-file-with-nodejs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a NodeJS built-in library called `fs` to do read/write operations.

**Step #1 - Import `fs`**

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

**Step #2 - Read the file**

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('punishmenthistory.json');
let punishments= JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(punishments);
```

Now you can use the `punishments` variable to check the data inside the JSON File. Also, you can change the data but it only resides inside the variable for now.

**Step #3 - Write to the File**

```
let data = JSON.stringify(punishments);
fs.writeFileSync('punishmenthistory.json', data);
```

**Full code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('punishmenthistory.json');
let punishments= JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(punishments);

let data = JSON.stringify(punishments);
fs.writeFileSync('punishmenthistory.json', data);
```

References:
https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/

Answer (score 2):

Use NodeJS File System https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html.

Here I have used [writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) API to write to file and [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) to read from file. Also, when writing don't forget to `JSON.stringify(data)` because you are writing the data to a JSON file.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Write Data
const data = {
"punishments": {
    "users": {
      "<example user who has a punishment history>": {
        "punishment-1567346": {
          "punishment-id": "1567346",
          "punishment-type": "mute",
          "punishment-reason": "<reason>"
        },
        "punishment-1567347": {
          "punishment-id": "1567347",
          "punishment-type": "ban",
          "punishment-reason": "<reason>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "outputfilepath", "outputfile.json"), JSON.stringify(data), "utf8");

// Read data
const rData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "outputfilepath", "outputfile.json"), "utf8");
const jsonData = JSON.parse(rData);
```

**Here is the working example,
https://repl.it/repls/OutrageousInbornBruteforceprogramming#index.js**

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this for reading:

```
const fs = require('fs')
function jsonReader(filePath, cb) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, fileData) => {
        if (err) {
            return cb && cb(err)
        }
        try {
            const object = JSON.parse(fileData)
            return cb && cb(null, object)
        } catch(err) {
            return cb && cb(err)
        }
    })
}
jsonReader('./customer.json', (err, customer) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return
    }
    console.log(customer.address) // => "Infinity Loop Drive"
})
```

and like this for writing:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const customer = {
    name: "Newbie Co.",
    order_count: 0,
    address: "Po Box City",
}
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(customer)
fs.writeFile('./newCustomer.json', jsonString, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error writing file', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully wrote file')
    }
})
```