# Not able to write table in .json to folder

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website, but cannot figure out how to write the data in .json which I can get to show up in the console..

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra'), // in python: from puppeteer_extra import puppeteerj
      StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth'),
      AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker'),
      fs = require("fs");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin())

const pageAddress = specificURL;
const processDataTable = async (tableHandle) => {
    const table = {};

    const heading = await tableHandle.$("thead tr th.heading-4");
    if (heading) {
        const title = await heading.getProperty('textContent').then(h => h.jsonValue());
        table[title] = [];
        const rows  = await tableHandle.$$("tbody tr")
        for (row of rows) {
            const r      = [],
                  head   = await row.$("th"),
                  data   = await row.$("td"),
                  hValue = await head.getProperty('textContent').then(v => v.jsonValue()),
                  dValue = await data.getProperty('textContent').then(v => v.jsonValue());
            if (head && data) {
                r.push(hValue);
                r.push(dValue);
                table[title].push(r);
            }
        }
    }
    return table;
}

(async () => {
    // spin up chrome
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({defaultViewport: null});

    // open up a new tab
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // go to the page we want to scrape
    await page.goto(pageAddress);

    // $: get one element with the specified selector
    // $$: get an array of elements that match the selector
    // selector ex.: table.table (a <table> with class="table", i.e <table class="table"></table>)
    const tableElements = await page.$$("table.table");
    const data = [];
    for (t of tableElements) {
        const tData = await processDataTable(t);
        data.push(tData);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    fs.writeFile('data.json', data);
    await browser.close();
})()
```

The console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) is working, and is displayed in my console appropriately but the writing function is not working like I was expecting it to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/write to a JSON file in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655643/how-to-read-write-to-a-json-file-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify it to write it to a file also, not just to print to the console.

```
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I see why I should be doing this now:) When I do though, I am getting this error do you see anything wront?: `node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "cb" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
    at maybeCallback (node:fs:189:3)
    at Object.writeFile (node:fs:2266:14)
    at C:\Users\PA3931\OneDrive - American National Insurance Company\Desktop\Edmunds-Scraper\index.js:55:8 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}`

Comment: Sorry, missed it, but it should actually be fs.writeFileSync since fs.writeFile is asynchronous. if you still want to use writeFile, you would need to do something like this

fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data), (err) => err && console.error(err));

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am getting the same error.. ergh