# add key:value to a .json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, file, fs

I have this `config.json` file:

```
{
  "account_name": {
    "min_len": "3",
    "max_len": "15",
    "upperCase": true,
    "lowerCase": true,
    "numbers": true,
    "specialChar": false,
    "capitalize": false,
    "duplication": false,
    "startWithCapital": false
  },
  "password": {
    "min_len": "6",
    "max_len": "20",
    "upperCase": true,
    "lowerCase": true,
    "numbers": true,
    "specialChar": true,
    "capitalize": false,
    "duplication": false,
    "StartWithCapital": false
  }
}
```

How can I add other values to this .json file from the code?
for exapmle :

```
var keysOpt = require('../config/config.json');
KeysOpt.name = "eric"
KeyPot.save() // will save the new field to the file itself
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a value in a json file and save it through node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685998/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-json-file-and-save-it-through-node-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use [**fs.writeFile()** method](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), to write back the JSON to the file.

This is how will be your code:

```
var keysOpt = require('../config/config.json');
keysOpt = JSON.parse(keysOpt);
KeysOpt.name = "eric";
// Make whatever changes you want to the parsed data
fs.writeFile('../config/config.json', JSON.stringify(keysOpt));
```

**Explanation:**

You just need to :

1. Parse the content of your JSON file, so you will get a JavaScript `object`.
2. You can then modify it or extend it with new data.
3. Before writing it back to the file you just need to make it a
   JSON string back again.
4. And finally write it back to the JSON file with `writeFile()` method.

**Note:**

- Note that you need to use `writeFileSyn()` to **Synchronously** write
  data to the file.
- And you should be aware that you should wait for the `writeFile()`
  callback to finish writing if you will try to write more than once to
  the same file.

You can check the nodeJS documentation for `fs.writeFile()` method, where it says:

> Note that it is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile` multiple times on the same
>   file without waiting for the `callback`. For this scenario,
>   `fs.createWriteStream` is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple like this :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var keysOpt = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../config/config.json'));
KeysOpt.name = "eric";
fs.writeFileSync('../config/config.json',JSON.stringify(KeysOpt,null,' '));
```