# json array value update using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

How to update a json file array values(particular values) using nodejs.

```
json file:

{
  "EmailSubjects": {
    "RegistrationMailSubject": "New User Registration",
    "ApprovedMailSubject": "new user Approval ",
    "RejectedMailSubject": "new user Your  ",
    "ForgetPasswordSubject": "password recovery"

  }
}
```

in this emailsubjects I want to update only registrationmailsubject value only.
how to achieve this..

Comment: The question is not clear: your "json file" is a str variabile, something that you are reading from txt file, a json object?

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = require('./path/to/file.json');
data.EmailSubjects.RegistrationMailSubject = 'New Text';

// if you want to persist the data
let fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('./path/to/file.json', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
EmailSubjects.RegistrationMailSubject = "my new value"
```

Comment: Do you need to save the updated JSON object back to the .json file?

Comment: If your question is about manipulating the json file content it was answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685998/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-json-file-and-save-it-through-node-js

Comment: This is also server side code in node. Also others have stated, please add more information to your question then we can help.