# How to edit json files with node.js

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to update a json file. I searched so much and I could not find any way to update a json file with node.js. If you have any answer please let me know. 
thanks.

Comment: you have seen this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685998/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-json-file-and-save-it-through-node-js

Comment: Hi ! The only way I know is to read the file, parse the values and modify them, then rewrite the file :(