# How can I edit a config file in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I edit a *config.json* file? I tried

```
const config = require("./config.json");
config.set("status", "online");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a value in a json file and save it through node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685998/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-json-file-and-save-it-through-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read in the file with something like `fs.readFile` then modify the content of the file and write back to it with `fs.writeFile`.