# How can I update local JSON properties with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object

**Context**

I have the current local JSON file with the input of some data:

```
[
{
"_id": "62bab08c83586a7bb36b46de",
"index": 0,
"tags": [
  "ea in minim in occaecat pariatur cillum",
  "ut exercitation minim officia enim cillum anim",
  "ad occaecat labore velit cupidatat enim proident",
  "consequat culpa qui occaecat sit sunt voluptate",
  "eiusmod excepteur adipisicing tempor ut Lorem do",
  "quis velit aliquip ad excepteur deserunt do",
  "dolor fugiat ea sit adipisicing labore in"
]
},
{
"_id": "62bab08c10365bb88f81cdf5",
"index": 1,
"tags": [
  "non laborum cillum commodo velit culpa commodo",
  "nisi aute magna laborum ut cillum velit",
  "in veniam ullamco officia aute deserunt ex",
  "dolor ullamco aliqua laborum ullamco officia mollit",
  "fugiat aliquip nostrud deserunt fugiat veniam veniam",
  "culpa eu irure ullamco ea deserunt ullamco",
  "labore quis quis enim magna duis cupidatat"
]
},
{
"_id": "62bab08cf0d1796087e71a27",
"index": 2,
"tags": [
  "esse labore aliqua sit voluptate mollit deserunt",
  "sint nulla minim veniam do nulla duis",
  "culpa enim laborum do magna voluptate amet",
  "commodo elit ad magna veniam proident duis",
  "aliquip ex dolore officia laboris sit qui",
  "esse anim velit ut quis do magna",
  "do culpa eu sint occaecat voluptate cillum"
]
},
{
"_id": "62bab08cbb8247421f46d095",
"index": 3,
"tags": [
  "ea aliqua cupidatat aute ipsum qui officia",
  "enim ad pariatur ex tempor pariatur irure",
  "in mollit aute sit occaecat non cupidatat",
  "adipisicing sint non elit nisi commodo sunt",
  "tempor veniam culpa exercitation in cillum pariatur",
  "non quis dolor in ea ut duis",
  "excepteur Lorem dolor qui tempor dolore reprehenderit"
]
},
{
"_id": "62bab08c642b523e6cc9ecd1",
"index": 4,
"tags": [
  "cillum nulla ipsum pariatur nisi ex in",
  "proident tempor aliquip id commodo sunt ut",
  "tempor qui ex laborum anim nisi excepteur",
  "consequat ea laborum cillum mollit enim consectetur",
  "nisi ut sint sunt non veniam ullamco",
  "proident exercitation culpa dolor duis enim qui",
  "commodo aliquip ipsum velit elit in nulla"
]
},
{
"_id": "62bab08c5702bc78e0e082db",
"index": 5,
"tags": [
  "deserunt sit labore veniam eiusmod tempor eu",
  "ut dolore est pariatur eiusmod cillum eu",
  "ex commodo voluptate Lorem incididunt dolor veniam",
  "labore ullamco quis et qui fugiat pariatur",
  "in duis ut tempor velit excepteur ut",
  "aute esse velit nisi et reprehenderit ea",
  "consectetur do aute et dolor ex do"
]
}
]
```

I need to change the current values locally in the JSON file.
Those are the currect values needed to be changed:

id => person_id

index => idx

tags => voiceLines

How can I change the local file using purely javascript?

Comment: For Each datum in data, create new object with correct property names, then copy the values.

Comment: Please don't dump garbage ("dfgdfgsdf...") into your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using NodeJS and not just browser, you would just use the `fs` library.

1. Read JSON file.
2. Update JSON.
3. Write JSON out.

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28175137) is how I'd probably do it.